# jhipster heroku lock on postgresql

Tags: postgresql, heroku, jhipster

As the documentation says "If your applicaiton is killed by Heroku when your Liquibase changelog is being applied, your database will be marked as "locked" by Liquibase. You will need to manually clean the lock table"

How I can clean the lock table? I tried with psql but I have no permissions to remove rows from pg_lock. Is there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have the rights to remove the rows in the table (use the same credentials as your application)

Comment: I misunderstood documentation, the lock is not set by Postgres, is set by Liquibase and it's on table databasechangeloglock. Thanks!